# Can I template match multiple templates and choose to detect the best match. OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am using template matching in OpenCV to match an arrow indicator to an image. There are three possible directions per image: left, right, and top.
I have 3 templates (one for each direction).

```
image1 = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\PaperWarrior\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\arrow1nobg.png")
image1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray1, 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
plt.imshow(binary, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
image1 = cv2.drawContours(image1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
plt.imshow(image1)
plt.show()

image2 = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\PaperWarrior\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\arrow2nobg.png")
image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray2, 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
plt.imshow(binary, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
image2 = cv2.drawContours(image2, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
plt.imshow(image2)
plt.show()

image3 = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\PaperWarrior\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\arrow3nobg.png")
image3 = cv2.cvtColor(image3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray3 = cv2.cvtColor(image3, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray3, 130, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
plt.imshow(binary, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
image3 = cv2.drawContours(image3, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
plt.imshow(image3)
plt.show()
```

I'm now stuck because I can not find a way for the source image to be scanned by each template and then provide the best match. Any thoughts?

Comment: Match your source image with every template iteratively. Note down the correlation score returned by the function. The best score would correspond to the best match.

Comment: it seems you run exactly the same code but with different image. You could put images on list and use `for`-loop to run the same code with different image. OR you could put code in function and run it with different images.